# Page won't validate due to invalid utf-8 character, but I can't find any invalid characters

Tags: php, validation, unicode, encoding, utf-8

The site in question: https://www.pepperheads-hotsauces.com

I'm playing janitor on this site and am having a hell of a time figuring out why this stupid thing won't validate. The error is "Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 858 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.
The error was: utf8 "\xC2" does not map to Unicode"

I'm tearing my hair out. I've been removing bits of code from the homepage trying to discern where this is coming from and can't seem to find the error. Does anyone know of a reasonable way to go about this? Am I missing something obvious? Or is it a CDATA script issue?

HALP!

Comment: Why cant you remove `Trinidad Scorpion Peppers ( Moruga ) are **�** `??

Comment: The page is completely blank (no server response) on Chrome and IE, so I think you have more serious problems than the validation issue. What the validator is saying (in a misleading way) is that the data contains byte 0xC2 on a page expected to be UTF-8, and the 0xC2 byte constitutes a data level error. It is impossible to tell from outside why your server sends such data. It’s not an invalid character but invalid data that does not represent any character.

Comment: This is driving me crazy... it's like there's a caching issue or something. Those blog posts are not even on the home page at all anymore (I removed them completely) yet you guys are all still seeing this. The blank page issue I solved (at least solved on all my browsers here) earlier today by disabling a trainwreck of an SEO plugin. *throws hands in the air* I don't know what else to do!

Comment: I cleared out the database cache and that seemed to solve the issue. So it was a caching issue after all. Man, this website is so jacked. I have my work cut out for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Line 858 of your page shows:

```
 Trinidad Scorpion Peppers ( Moruga ) are � ...</strong></p>
```

try using htmlspecialchars around whatever that character is.

more info can be found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: I don't understand this. Line 858 of the code is currently `</div>`. Those blog posts were the first thing I removed in attempt to fix this. What's more, that character doesn't even exist anywhere in the actual blog post. The posts reads "Trinidad Scorpion Peppers (Moruga) are now available." (I had even edited out the extra spaces between the parenthetical), so that line doesn't exist in the database anymore... wth?